# Does changing acoustic guitar strings require a re-setup?

Tags: guitar, strings, intonation, setup

I'm currently using D'Addario EZ920 (0.12-0.54) and I'm planning to change to D'Addario EJ16 (0.12-0.53) which is slightly lighter. I'm wondering if this will affect the intonation and needs readjustment.

They are almost the same but in terms of diameter the EJ16 is slightly lighter.

EZ920: .012, .016, .025, .034, .044, .054
EJ16:  .012, .016, .024, .032, .042, .053

Comment: Some would say you should re-setup your instrument after 6 months, even with the same strings.  Anyway, tweaking the action, intonation (on some models), and relief does not take long, so why not?

Answer (score 3):

Even though the gauges are close they are not identical. There also will likely be variances in string tension between two sets that are the same brand but different types because of materials, type of core, etc. For that reason it’s a good idea to at least check the neck relief and adjust the truss rod if necessary for optimal feel.

Most acoustic guitars have fixed bridges so intonation adjustment is not an option but if it is then that should be at least checked with a tuner and adjusted as well.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt whether even the most discerning player will notice the difference in *feel* between the two sets. The *sound* may be very, very slightly different, but that will mainly be due to new strings always being brighter, anyway, than the old ones just taken off.

Tension-wise, there's really no need to adjust anything, the truss rod will happily cope, and the intonation will be quite adequate. Get changing!